# java nested loop logic for triangle's left side

Tags: java, loops, nested, logic

Okay I am so tired of struggling with this and right off the bat I feel really stupid so please be gentle.. I've searched the stack overflow and web and still not finding anything.  I am using a nested loop to create a triangle that looks like this:

```
              1
          1   2   1
      1   2   4   2   1
  1   2   4   8   4   2   1
```

...etc. through 128 in the center column.

My loop for the left side renders to the right of my triangle instead of to the left. I'm pretty sure that after I receive an answer I will be hitting my head w/the palm of my hand and saying duh repeatedly. Anyway thanks for your help. I especially want an explanation of the logic. Here is the code.

```
public class Pyramid_center_x2_0519 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    for (int centerColumn = 1; centerColumn <= 128; centerColumn *=2){
        for (int j = 8; j > 1; j--) {
            System.out.printf("%7s", "");
        }

        for (int rightSide = centerColumn; rightSide > 0; rightSide/=2){

            System.out.printf("%7d", rightSide);
        }

        for (int leftSide = 2; leftSide < centerColumn; leftSide*=2){

            System.out.print( leftSide );           
        }

        System.out.println("");
    }
 }
}
```

Here is the way it renders:
[image]

Thanks again.......

UPDATED CODE 12 P.M. 5-31-16: I understand Java prints left to right.  Below I have placed the left hand loop before the right side loop but my spacing in front of the triangle is not behaving. Thank you all... again

```
    for (int centerColumn = 1; centerColumn <= 128; centerColumn *=2){
        for (int j = 8; j > 0; j--) {

            System.out.printf("%7s", "");
        }
        for (int leftSide = 1; leftSide < centerColumn; leftSide*=2){

            System.out.print( leftSide );           
        }
        for (int rightSide = centerColumn; rightSide > 0; rightSide/=2){

            System.out.printf("%7d", rightSide);
        }

        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: what you are trying to do simply doesn't work. You cannot print "to the left". printf just keeps on writing in the direction of writing.

Comment: You have to change your algorythm and actually write the numbers in the order you want them to be displayed. The logic for that shouldn't be that hard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you already solved most of your Problems and your last updated version already prints the numbers correctly.

The only thing you still need to fix is the formatting to make it look nice.

Starting from your current code there are 2 things that need changing:

1. All your printed numbers are supposed to take up the same space (7). You already formatted your "right side" printed numbers in that way, all you have to do is do the same for the other numbers.
2. You currently allways add 8*7 spaces in front of the line, which of course isn't correct. If you look at the pyramid you can clearly see that 8*7 spaces is correct for the first line, but the second line would need 7*7 spaces in front, the third 6*7 etc. pp.
   That means to get the correct formatting for you pyramid you have to modify your loop that prints the spaces to run 1 less time with each iteration of your main loop.

Here is one way how you could update your code to add those 2 changes (I added comments in front of the lines i changed as explanation):

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    /** I added this counter to keep track 
     *  of what iteration/line the loop currently is (see 2.)
     */ 
    int iteration = 0;
    for (int centerColumn = 1; centerColumn <= 128; centerColumn *=2){

        /** Here we changed the loop condition 
        *   from "j > 0" to "j > iteration"
        *   (So as iteration gets bigger, the loop runs less often)
        */
        for (int j = 8; j > iteration; j--) {
            System.out.printf("%7s", "");
        }
        for (int leftSide = 1; leftSide < centerColumn; leftSide*=2){
            /** This should be self explanatory. 
             *  You already did the same for rightSide.
             *  This will take care of 1.
             */
            System.out.printf("%7d",  leftSide );           
        }
        for (int rightSide = centerColumn; rightSide > 0; rightSide/=2){
           System.out.printf("%7d", rightSide);
        }
        /** Here we increment our counter with each iteration aka line that is printed */
        iteration++;
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! Thank you for the time you took to walk me through your logic and the thorough explanation including what was wrong with my code. I was stuck as to how to decrement the spaces in front.  Such a simple solution.  I was trying to use an additional for loop of some type to do the decrementing and couldn't get that to work.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way you can print left side after right and center side.

Java prints from left to the right.
(unless you use some arabic encoding)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**Edited:**  First try to put your spaces before putting your number in triangle(here my first inner for loop is doing) then apply some logic to print the number at its position accordingly.

```
static DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#");
public static void main(String[] args) {

    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i += 2) {
        for (int k = 0; k < (4 - i / 2); k++) {  // first
            System.out.print(" ");
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {  // second
            if (Math.pow(2, j) <= i)
                System.out.print(df.format(Math.pow(2, j)));
            else
                System.out.print(df.format(Math.pow(2, i - j - 1)));

        }

        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing this would work but the df throws an error- and I am hoping you can walk me through your logic- or help me modify my loops to get the left side to loop before the right. Many thanks.

Comment: @amicngh: The downvote is for simply pasting finished code with nothing but "try this" added. This won't help the asker learn anything and it isn't even what his question was (which was: why does his loop not print to the left). If he wanted a finished piece of code he could probably take one of the thousand you find online for this very common programming exercise. In short: Just a bad answer imho.

Comment: @911DidBush: I assumed OP already know that java execute statements from left to right so only matters here the logic to print the numbers in that sequence, therefore I gave him logic to print the numbers in reverse order as he could get thousand triangle codes online.However I have updated my answer.

Comment: That seems to make more sense- though I don't have experience with df and what purpose it performs.  I'll mess with this and get back to you.

Comment: @nacent_coder Math.pow(x,y) function returns double therfore if we dont format (DecimalFormat is doing) the double it would print in decimal format(i.e. 24.0) which we dont want.

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach is not good. Try this algorithm:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int levels = 8;

        int lastLevelWidth = levels*2 + 1;

        for (int i=0; i<levels; i++) {
            int blankPositions = (lastLevelWidth - 1)/2 - i;

            for (int j=0; j<blankPositions; j++)
                print(" ");

            int levelWidth = i*2 + 1;
            int numberPositionsPerSide = (levelWidth-1)/2;

            for (int j=0; j<numberPositionsPerSide; j++) {
                print(Math.pow(2, j));
            }

            print(Math.pow(2, i));

            for (int j=numberPositionsPerSide-1; j>=0; j--) {
                print(Math.pow(2, j));
            }

            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static void print(String string) {
        System.out.print(string);

        int spaces = 5 - string.length();

        for (int i=0; i<spaces; i++)
            System.out.print(" ");
    }

    public static void print(double n) {
        print(Integer.toString((int)n));
    }
}
```

Comment: Any help with my existing code would be appreciated. I need to relate the logic within my current structure.

Comment: You have no narrative on what you are doing so.... although I prefer to have my original code modified so I can see in 'this particular case' what I'm doing wrong...- if you could comment in your code or provide anything narrative on your code and why it is better it would be greatly appreciated.